# Is this usage of abbreviation of "it is" correct?

Tags: contractions, orthography

I just complimented a user on how quickly he answered my question, upon which he replied:

> A lot of it's luck, really.

I'd definitely not write it like that. Although using contractions quite excessively (as the previous sentence illustrates), I still feel that something's wrong here, not being able to put my finger on the exact issue.

Is the above correct and I'm just noticing it because it's not common application? Or is it incorrect and if so, what's the grammatical error description?

I feel that if we regard the whole subject, i.e. "*a lot of it*" and then add the abbreviated predicate, it'll sound correct but that'd require something like

> Alotofit's luck, really.

or possibly

> "A-lot-of-it" 's luck, really

Answer (score 2):

"A lot" refers to the amount of "it" that is luck.  The sentence without the contraction is "A lot of it is luck, really."  The sentence is written correctly.